# Product Architecture

Tags: database-design, architecture, saas

I have a product that offers a small lead management system. The architecture of product is simple so far. I have tables called 'companies', 'users', 'leads'. Users within a company have CRUD rights on leads. Now companies want their agents to have rights to operate leads. So we can ask companies to add their agent as a user within the company but there is a problem. Each user needs to have a unique email to register. So if one agent serves 5 companies they can't be added as a user by each of them. What should be the ideal way to handle this.

Thought of having separate database for each company so that problem of unique email is resolved but I'm not sure how to manage multiple databases for updates

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what platform your application is written for.  On the Lotus Notes / Domino platform this is exactly how this situation is managed.  Each customer has their own database in a unique NSF file, then an NTF template is used to refresh the design of each NSF.  Other platforms presumably have similar functionality available.

Comment: Its PHP, My Sql